# Effect of anonymous namespaces on methods, member variables and special member functions like constructors

Tags: c++, class, linkage

If I define class inside an anonymous namespace, what does that mean for its methods, member variables and special member functions?

Are inline methods and special member functions are still inline or do they have internal linkage?

What about inline member variables?

Comment: Note that [`inline` is not particularly related to linkage](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.inline#2).

Answer (score 2):

From the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces), all the members of an unnamed namespace (or anonymous namespace) have internal linkage.

> Its members have potential scope from their point of declaration to the end of the translation unit, and have internal linkage.